# How to call a copy constructor of a class from the same class using another constructor in java

Tags: java

I was learning about calling multiple constructors within the same class using one of the constructors.(so that i wont have to create multiple objects).After learning the concept of constructor chaining I found out about the "this" keyword,
But i don't know how to call the COPY constructor from another constructor within the same class using this concept.Please help!!!

Comment: Do you have some code to demonstrate what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
class YourClass{


private int x;
private int y;

YourClass(YourClass obj, int z){
    this(obj);
    //do something with z
}

YourClass(YourClass obj){
     this.x = obj.getX();
     this.y = obj.getY();
}
```

.....